# Amcharts V4 plating a chart in percent rather than absolute using valueYShow

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

I'm trying to create a chart using AMCharts V4. The values are given in absolute, and I want to have the chart in percentages: values, y-axis, etc.

The docs are here: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/plotting-series-from-calculated-values/

However, I'm having some trouble. Pls consider the following codepen forked from the official AMCharts documentation:

https://codepen.io/otmezger/pen/RwVzmjv

As the docs suggest, I have `valueAxis.calculateTotals = true;` enabled.

The line `series.dataFields.valueYShow = "totalPercent";` or `series.dataFields.valueYShow = "percent";` renders the graph useless.

only if I disable them, the graph will show in absolute numbers.

what am I missing? how can I make `series.dataFields.valueYShow = "percent";` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use percent values in the series, you need to set `calculatePercent` to true on the series as explained [here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/using-percent-values-in-series/)

```
series.calculatePercent = true;
series.dataFields.valueYShow = "percent";
series.tooltipText = "{dateX}: [b]{valueY.percent}[/]%";
```

Demo:

```js
// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Add data
chart.data = [{
  "date": new Date(2018, 0, 1),
  "value": 10
}, {
  "date": new Date(2018, 0, 2),
  "value": 15
}, {
  "date": new Date(2018, 0, 3),
  "value": 2
}];

// Create axes
var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
dateAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.calculateTotals = true;
valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.adapter.add("text", function(text) {
  return text + "%";
});


// Create series
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = "value";
series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
series.calculatePercent = true;
series.dataFields.valueYShow = "percent";

series.tooltipText = "{dateX}: [b]{valueY.percent}[/]%";
series.strokeWidth = 2;

var bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
bullet.circle.stroke = am4core.color("#fff");
bullet.circle.strokeWidth = 2;

// Finish up setting chart up
chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```